# MonkeyRunner cannot run on Git Shell. Receiving @echo: command not found

Tags: android, git, shell, monkeyrunner

I am trying to run Android's `MonkeyRunner` but having problems running it from my `Git Shell`.

When I run:
`monkeyrunner.bat`
it gives me this error.

```
$ monkeyrunner.bat
/c/AndroidSDK/tools/monkeyrunner.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
/c/AndroidSDK/tools/monkeyrunner.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/AndroidSDK/tools/monkeyrunner.bat: line 2: `rem Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project'
```

How do I fix this? I tried running my script with it too but still same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a "monkeyrunner.sh"?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Do you mean in the AndroidSDK/tools directory? There is no `monkeyrunner.sh`.

Comment: That's a Windows batch file. It isn't going to work on a non-Windows machine. You need a shell script version of that file (this is what Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen was getting at).

Comment: @EtanReisner ohhhh got it. Sorry I'm relatively inexperienced in Linux. Is there an easy way to convert a batch file to shell script?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd need to understand the script and know what the appropriate equivalents are to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `git-shell` is a login shell for SSH accounts to provide restricted Git access.

It permits execution only of server-side Git commands implementing the pull/push functionality, plus custom commands present in a subdirectory named `git-shell-commands` in the user’s home directory.

Therefore, if you don't have `monkeyrunner` (notice, not .bat or .sh here) setup in the `git-shell-commands` you won't be able to run it.